# How to use elements in a list to create an object for a class

Tags: python, list, class, variables

i've created a class containing the following constructor:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, student_id, student_name, student_marks):
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.student_name = student_name
        self.student_marks = student_marks
```

i'm accessing a text file that contains lines of text in the following format:

```
1,Harvey Specter,97
2,Mike Ross,84
3,Krimhilde Aust,94
```

first integer being student id, string being name and last integer being mark.

I would like to iterate over each line in the text file, convert it to a list and use the elements in the list to create an object for my class. So far I have this:\

```
with open('records.txt', 'r') as records:
    for line in records:
        line = line.replace(',',' ')
        x = line.split()
        x[1:3] = [' '.join(x[1:3])]
```

I would like to, over each iteration, create a new object for my class, something like this: (I know this is wrong)

```
x[0] = Student(x[0],x[1],x[2]
```

The problem here is in my variable. I need to (and I know this is wrong, please dont flame me lol) *dynamically* create a unique variable for each list that my for loop will create so that I can send a new object to my class.

I think I need to create a new list of student ID's and use that to create variables?

Comment: "dynamically create a unique variable for each list that my for loop will create" Why do you think so? Each time through the list, you use `Student(x[0],x[1],x[2])`, and create a new `Student`. No problem. "so that I can send a new object to my class." I have no idea what you think "send an object to a class" means.

Comment: for starters, use the `csv` module, don't mess around with manually parsing your csv.

Comment: In any case, no, you *never* need to dynamically create a variable. Use a *container* like a `list` or `dict`. A list here seems like a reasonable way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file format looks like `csv`. Try this code:

```
import csv

students = []

with open('records.txt', 'r') as records:
    reader = csv.reader(records)
    for row in reader:
        student = Student(
            student_id = row[0],
            student_name = row[1],
            student_marks = row[2]
        )
        students.append(student)
```

Comment: @adirabargil Just fixed it, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
students=[]
with open('records.txt', 'r') as records:
    for line in records:
        #no need to replace all commas with spaces
        id,name,mark = line.split(",")
        #add student to student list
        students.append(Student(id,name,mark))
```